# Login issue when connecting to Visual Studio (IIS Express) from iPad

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 app which is deployed to Azure. Now, to test it locally, I run my app using Visual Studio (2019), then I launch the site in my mobile devices browser.

The issue is that when I do it from my iPad, and login, after I enter username/password, and click login, I am back to the login screen immediately.

I have tried different browsers on the iPad. I have tried clearing the cache on them. I have restarted my PC, and my iPad. Still the same problem. I don't see any errors. **But it works if I use my iPhone to login or from a desktop browser**. If it is deployed to Azure, I can login from everywhere, including iPad.

I debug in the code and I even see that the login is successful and the return URL is the right URL:

```
 var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    await UserManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user?.Id, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow));
                    await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user?.Id);

                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

I even tried to force things by putting the following code at the top of my Login POST method:

```
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
                
                Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Can someone help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this will some day save someone's hours of work. The problem was due to having the CookieSameSite in the Startup.Auth.cs:

```
       app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
       {
           ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
           AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
           LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
           SlidingExpiration = true,
           CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
           Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
           {
               OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
           }
       });
```

Once I removed `CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,`, it started to work.